# How can I stop the function execution in my test?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I test this case?

I have a variable in the setup:

```
setup() {
      const address = `${process.env.VAR_ENV}`
  onMounted(async () => {
        const stop = await isContinuing(address)
```

The function `await isContinuing(address)` is executing when the test is run. How can I make the function *not* run when the test is ran?

My test's undefined wrap variable

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(App, {
  })
})

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  it('test to verify if initial section.', () => {
    const expected = 0
    expect(wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'section' }).element.value).toBe(
      expected
    )
  })
```

Comment: @MichalLevý can you write your answer please

Answer (score 1):

Jest (and I assume most test frameworks) sets NODE_ENV enviromental variable to `test`. So you can use a simple `if` statement to not execute something in tests:

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  const stop = await isContinuing(address)
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly fine in my project that is using Jest (via Vue CLI)

Comment: So if it does not work for you, you should probably specify how **exactly** it does not work (for example what error is thrown instead just saying "does not work") and also update your questing with details about your project/testing setup - what test runner are you using etc.